# Is it possible to extend .Net XML documentation for Web API?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to use auto generating documentation for my Web API project.  I have an ApplicationController decorated with a..

```
/// <param name="application">
```

This is of type Application and has public properties eg..

```
[DataContract]
public class Application : ICanBeAuthenticated
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Email (string): Required. Email address of the applicant. Must be a valid email address.
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

...

}
```

I can retrieve the summary tag for Email, however I'd like to be access the property name 'Email' to separate it from its description, any ideas?

Ideally I'd like to be able to have something like..

```
    /// <name>
    /// Email (string)
    /// </name>
    /// <description>
    /// Required. Email address of the applicant. Must be a valid email address.
    /// </description>
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
```

Comment: may I ask you why you wanna do this? By default the content of summary is the default description, the "name" tag it's a redundant info.

Comment: Because I want to have a table where the left column is property name and the right column contains the description